# Dynamic button in navbar not displaying correct

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm having trouble with dynamic button in navbar. Here's the code:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <button menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title>{{action.name}}</ion-title>

        <ion-buttons end>
            <button *ngIf="view.searchable">
                <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <button *ngIf="view.creatable">
                <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <button (click)="showMenu($event)">
                <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Output:

[image: navbar]

Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, the `*ngIf`is causing that issue (you can try by removing it, and the button is properly displayed). In order to solve it, you can change it like this:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <button menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <ion-title>{{action.name}}</ion-title>

        <ion-buttons *ngIf="view.searchable" end>
            <button>
                <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-buttons *ngIf="view.creatable" end>
            <button>
                <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button (click)="showMenu($event)">
                <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
            </button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Notice that I bind the `*ngIf`to the `ion-buttons` element instead of the `button` directly. Please take a look at this [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AEC7Xc?p=preview).

Comment: This solution works fine. But I'm trying to avoid this cos it doesn't look nice. Anyway, thank you.